# Should we add some content on our site that is widely known to get more users on our site?

Tags: discussion, content-quality

(Obviously, we shouldn't be focusing solely on getting users in a *private beta*, but I want to add some content to the site and the current content is limited.

Let me give an example. Can I do a "Q & A style" of *what are the curved lines by some of the pin numbers?* or should I not post anything like that. Here's some obvious pros/cons:

### Pros:

- Can help get new users if they are searching this question. If we grow enough to be 90% of the time in the top 3 listings on Google, we might gain a large chunk of new users that way
- If done correctly, it can add an example of well content to our site
- We can gain reputation!!! (Just kidding about that last one...)
- Help with question count to try to improve the odds of this beta surviving and give it a "jump start"

### Cons:

- Wastes server resources
- Some users who don't know it's a Q & A post might downvote it because the OP didn't "put much effort into it" by not Googling it.

Answer (score 4):

The very motivation behind me participating on Stack Exchange sites is that we share and, in many instances, generate **knowledge**, that is usually hard to find and/or not widely available or known.

Simply duplicating content that can be found in lots of other reputable sites is in my belief, not what we are here to do, and we should refrain from doing so.

However, if we **have information to add** to such widely available content, then yes, it is worth posting on this site.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing wrong with this, and in fact, encourage it to some extent. I've done a couple of question/answers myself.

I come mainly from SO so my opinion is based on that. Google any programming question, no matter how simple or basic it is, and you'll find a stack overflow result on the first page.

Arduino.SE can be the one-stop for people's Arduino questions. Is that not the goal of this site? Sure the answers are out there, but most of the questions on this site (and many on SO) are out there on Google, too. But the point of SE is to have them all in one place.

So that's a fine question if you ask me. Sure it'll be in the Arduino docs, but you won't be able to ask Google "what are the curved lines by some of the pin numbers [on Arduino]?" and find the answer. You could if it was on Arduino.SE.

Also: all the pros clearly outweigh the cons in your list.